# How to produce sine wave heat generator?

Tags: experimental-physics, electronics, experimental-technology

I have taken a lab course this semester and in the experiment of finding thermal diffusivity of brass they are using square wave heat generator(by a simple circuit which gets on and off at regular intervals connected to a const heat generator). But the theory to determine diffusity from these data points is very tough and also a bit approximate since we have to do an integration over a set of data points(for Fourier analysis) and we end up using Simpsons rule as we only have discrete points of data. So I want to get more definite results by using sine wave heat generator.

As it turns out I do not know that much electronics to design one and could not find anything of this sort in literature. Can anyone help me? Even a good link to some existing document will be appreciated.

Comment: What heater power do you need? 100W? Get yourself a function generator and a DC-coupled audio amplifier. Today you can get perfectly suitable 100W D-class power stages for under $100.

Comment: Can those give me a very large time period? Say 10 minutes? Because otherwise I cannot take data points.

Comment: Yes, with a DC coupled amplifier and a modern digital sine wave generator that should't be a problem. They usually go down to $1\mu Hz$. You have to keep in mind that the power is the square of the voltage, so the effective heating frequency will be twice the frequency you set on the generator!

Comment: Apologies... I was talking nonsense by shortcut. The power is, of course, not the square of the voltage but proportional to the square of the voltage if the load is an Ohmic resistor. The conclusion that the frequency of the power modulation is twice that of the voltage is correct.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Mr. R. Goldberg, Jr.  suggests putting a hi-intensity lamp (or 4 or 8 of them) on a turntable and rotating said assembly so as to sweep the beams across your test subject.